# Expected value of applying the sigmoid function to a normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, integration

#### Short version:

I would like to calculate the expected value if you apply the sigmoid function $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ to a normal distribution with expected value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

If I'm correct this corresponds to the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\ e^{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} } dx$$

However, I can't solve this integral. I've tried manually, with Maple and with Wolfram|Alpha, but didn't get anywhere.

#### Some background info (why I want to do this):

Sigmoid functions are used in artificial neural networks as an activation function, mapping a value of $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$. Often this value is used directly in further calculations but sometimes (e.g. in [RBM's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_machine#Restricted_Boltzmann_machine)) it's first stochastically rounded to a 0 or a 1, with the probabililty of a 1 being that value. The stochasticity helps the learning, but is sometimes not desired when you finally use the network. Just using the normal non-stochastic methods on a network that you trained stochastically doesn't work though. It changes the expected result, because (in short):

$$\operatorname{E}[S(X)] \neq S(\operatorname{E}[X])$$

for most X. However, if you approximate X as a normal distribution and could somehow calculate this expected value, you could eliminate most of the bias. That's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt that there's a closed-form solution.  However, here's a series in powers of $\sigma$:

$$
 \left( {{\rm e}^{-{\mu}}}+1 \right) ^{-1}+{\frac { \left( {
{\rm e}^{-{\mu}}}-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{-{\mu}}}}{2\, \left( {{\rm e}
^{-{\mu}}}+1 \right) ^{3}}}{{\sigma}}^{2}+{\frac { \left( {
{\rm e}^{-3\,{\mu}}}-11\,{{\rm e}^{-2\,{\mu}}}+11\,{{\rm e}^{-{
\mu}}}-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{-{\mu}}}}{8\, \left( {{\rm e}^{-{\mu}
}}+1 \right) ^{5}}}{{\sigma}}^{4}+{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-{\mu}
}} \left( {{\rm e}^{-5\,{\mu}}}-57\,{{\rm e}^{-4\,{\mu}}}+302\,{
{\rm e}^{-3\,{\mu}}}-302\,{{\rm e}^{-2\,{\mu}}}+57\,{{\rm e}^{-{
\mu}}}-1 \right) }{48\, \left( {{\rm e}^{-{\mu}}}+1 \right) ^{7}}}{{
\sigma}}^{6}+{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-{\mu}}}
 \left( {{\rm e}^{-7\,{\mu}}}-247\,{{\rm e}^{-6\,{\mu}}}+4293\,{
{\rm e}^{-5\,{\mu}}}-15619\,{{\rm e}^{-4\,{\mu}}}+15619\,{
{\rm e}^{-3\,{\mu}}}-4293\,{{\rm e}^{-2\,{\mu}}}+247\,{{\rm e}^{
-{\mu}}}-1 \right) }{384\, \left( {{\rm e}^{-{\mu}}}+1 \right) ^{9}}}
{{\sigma}}^{8}+O \left( {{\sigma}}^{10} \right) 
$$

EDIT: To obtain this, first do the change of variables $x = \mu + \sigma t$.  The
integral becomes
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{-t^2/2}}{1 + e^{-\mu - \sigma t}}\ dt $$
Now take the Maclaurin series $$\frac{1}{1+e^{-\mu - \sigma t}} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\mu}} + \frac{e^{-\mu} \sigma t}{(1+e^{-\mu})^2} + \frac{e^{-\mu} ( e^{-\mu} - 1) \sigma^2 t^2}{(1+e^{-\mu})^3} + \ldots$$
and integrate term by term.

Comment: Hi Robert, could you comment on the derivation of that series?  Where does it come from?

Answer (score 18):

Apart from the the MacLaurin approximation, the usual way to compute that integral in Statistics is to approximate the sigmoid with a *probit* function.
More specifically $\mathrm{sigm}(a) \approx \Phi(\lambda a)$ with $\lambda^2=\pi/8$.
Then the result would be:
$$\int \mathrm{sigm}(x) \, N(x \mid \mu,\sigma^2) \, dx
\approx \int \Phi(\lambda x) \, N(x \mid \mu,\sigma^2) \, dx
= \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\lambda^{-2} + \sigma^2}}\right).$$

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken somewhere, $\lambda = \pi / 8$ [isn't a particularly good value of $\lambda$ to use](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/dougalsutherland/8509978). The best value, in terms of max-norm convergence, seems to be about 0.588 (about $\pi / 5.35$).

Comment: I should also note for posterity that, since the equality wasn't obvious to me, [here's a nice proof](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61098/9964).

Comment: Could you post the result of the more general form $\int \text{sigm}(ax+b) N(x \vert \mu, \sigma^2) dx$ ?

Comment: @korkinof I have not seen this used before. Can you provide some references?

Comment: @Danica note that korkinof's answer defines $\lambda^2 = \pi/8$ which gives $\lambda = \sqrt{\pi/8} \approx 0.63$ which is much closer to your numeric solution.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00091 has an in-depth look at expectations of the sigmoid. That article suggests $\lambda \approx 0.61$ based on Monte Carlo estimates.

Comment: Hah, yes, you're definitely right @STJ, a silly mistake. Also, my 8-year-old notebook above roughly minimizes the absolute distance between the CDFs, which might not be quite the best approximation for the purpose of computing this integral.

Answer (score 11):

Since I do not have enough reputation to comment, I'll instead add a new answer. @korkinof's answer is almost correct. The final integral evaluates to the following:
\begin{equation}
\int \operatorname{sigmoid}(x) \mathcal{N}(x; \mu, \sigma^2) \mathrm{d}x \approx \int \Phi(\lambda x) \mathcal{N}(x; \mu, \sigma^2) \mathrm{d}x = \Phi\left(\frac{\lambda \mu}{\sqrt{1 + \lambda^2 \sigma^2}}\right).
\end{equation}
I verified my answer through simulation.

Comment: @Smoke did explain his / her reasons for posting the answer, and the seem compelling. For example, the answer fixes a bug in korkinof's.

Comment: Could you post the result of the more general form $\int \text{sigm}(ax+b) N(x \vert \mu, \sigma^2) dx$ ?

Comment: That is the same answer! Just pull lambda out of the root.