# Expectation and Variance of Gaussian going through Rectified Linear or Sigmoid function

Tags: probability, integration

When you apply a Gaussian probability densityfunction to Rectified Linear/Sigmoid function, 
you will get a rectified(*)/distorted Gaussian function.

(*)rectified Gaussian function is a mixture of delta and truncated gaussian as shown belown
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectified_Gaussian_distribution

I am wondering, what is the Expectation and Variance of this rectified/distorted Gaussian?

The Expectation of distorted Gaussian from Sigmoid is shown below.
[Expected value of applying the sigmoid function to a normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207861/expected-value-of-applying-the-sigmoid-function-to-a-normal-distribution)

How about Variance? or Expectation and Variance of rectified Gaussian from Rectified Linear?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like what you are a calling a rectified Gaussian is $Y=\max[c,X]$, where $c$ is a constant and $X$ is Gaussian (say, mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2>0$).  You can find $E[Y]$, $E[Y^2]$, and $Var(Y)$ easily via the law of total expectation (condition on $X\geq c$ and $X<c$).

Comment: So for example rectifying at $0$ for a Normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ you get an expectation of $\mu\,\left(1-\Phi\left( -\dfrac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right) + \sigma\,\phi\left(-\dfrac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)$

Comment: Thanks for advice, yes I was able to derive same equation for expectation. But Variance is very hard and I got a very long equation... too big to paste it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma)$. "Rectified" Gaussian is then $Y = \max(0, X)$. For both the expectation and the variance use the law of total expectation, as suggested by Michael. I'll also make use of the first two moments of the truncated normal distribution, which are readily available from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}Y &= \mathbb{E}[X|X>0]\mathbb{P}(X>0) + 0\times\mathbb{P}(X\leq0) 
\end{align}

Notice that the random variable $X|X>0$ is a truncated normal (with parameters $\mu, \sigma, 0, \infty$) which has a mean $\mu + \sigma \frac{\phi(-\mu/\sigma)}{1-\Phi(-\mu/\sigma)}$. Hence, as already established:
$$
\mathbb{E}Y = \mu \left(1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right) + \sigma \phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)
$$

For the variance
\begin{align}
Var(Y) &= \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - (\mathbb{E}Y)^2 \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X^2|X>0]\mathbb{P}(X>0) + 0\times\mathbb{P}(X\leq0)- (\mathbb{E}Y)^2 
\end{align}

The only thing needed to calculate the above which we don't have is the second moment of the truncated normal, $\mathbb{E}[X^2|X>0]$, which can be obtained from its mean and the variance:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X^2|X>0] &= \sigma^2\left( 1+ \frac{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} \phi(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma})}{1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)} - \frac{\phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} \right)^2}{\left(1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)^2}\right) + 
\left(\mu + \sigma \frac{\phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)} \right)^2 \\
& = \sigma^2 +\mu^2 +\mu\sigma \frac{\phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)}
\end{align}

You can expand $(\mathbb{E}Y)^2$ and try to simplify a bit further:
\begin{align}
Var(Y) &= (\sigma^2 + \mu^2)\left(1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right) + \mu\sigma \phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) - \left(\mu \left(1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right) + \sigma \phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) \right)^2 \\
&= \mu^2\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\left(1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right) + \mu\sigma\phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\left(2\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)-1 \right) + \sigma^2\left(1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) - \phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Mean and variance derivations are given by Maxime Beauchamp, "On numerical computation for the distribution of the convolution of N independent rectified Gaussian variables" at http://www.numdam.org/item/JSFS_2018__159_1_88_0/

$$
\operatorname{E}[X^+] = \mu \left(1 - \Phi \left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} \right)\right) + \sigma \phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} \right) \\
\operatorname{Var}[X^+] = (\mu^2 + \sigma^2) \left(1 - \Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} \right)\right) + \mu \sigma \phi \left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma} \right) - \operatorname{E}[X^+]^2
$$