# Expectation of probit of inner product of a gaussian random vector

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

How can we solve for $\int_{s} \Phi(\langle w, s\rangle) \mathcal{N}(s; \mu, \Sigma)\,ds$ i.e. expected value of probit over the inner product of Bivariate/Multivariate Gaussian Random Vector, where $\mathcal{\phi}$ is the probit function?

Essentially, I am trying to solve  [Expected value of applying the sigmoid function to a normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207861/expected-value-of-applying-the-sigmoid-function-to-a-normal-distribution) but for the multi-variate case with the sigmoid over an inner product with some vector w.

Comment: What is probit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the notation $a^\top b$ instead of $\langle a, b\rangle$.

If $S \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ then $U := w^\top S \sim N(w^\top \mu, w^\top S w)$.

Your integral is $$E[\Phi(w^\top S)] = E[\Phi(U)].$$

Let $Z \sim N(0, 1)$ be independent of $U$, and note that $\Phi(u) = P(Z \le u) = P(Z \le U \mid U = u)$.

Then $$E[\Phi(U)] = E[P(Z \le U \mid U)] = P(Z \le U).$$

Finally, note that $Z-U \sim N(-w^\top \mu, w^\top S w + 1)$, so
$$P(Z \le U) = P(Z-U \le 0) = \Phi\left(\frac{w^\top \mu}{\sqrt{w^\top S w + 1}}\right)$$

Note that the above argument is an adaptation of an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61098/21801) that was mentioned in the comments of an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/381375/43949) to the question you linked.

Comment: Actually I have been trying to do something like this, but am not sure how to go about proving the expectation equality  $\int_S \phi(w^{T}S)\mathcal{N}(S;\mu,\Sigma)dS  =  \int_U \phi(U)\mathcal{N}(U;\mu_U,\Sigma_U)dU$, where $\mu_U = w^T\mu, \Sigma_U = w^T\Sigma w$. Can we say it is as simple as substituting $U = w^TS$ and then simply working with the distribution of U? Thanks!

Comment: @shishir It is much easier to think of the expectation of the random variable without thinking about integrals. The equality $E[\Phi(w^\top S)] = E[\Phi(U)]$ holds because we defined $U := w^\top S$; the only difficulty lies in understanding what the distribution of $U$ is, but because $S$ is normal this is relatively easy. It is very difficult to deal with the integral and densities (note that the integral on the left is a multivariate integral while the integral on the right is a univariate integral), but in principle yes you could obtain the equality by a substitution/change-of-variables.

Comment: I see. Thanks a ton!!