# The distribution of the softmax of normal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Given $k$ independent variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$ following normal distributions, where $x_i$ follows $\mathcal N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$, what is the distribution of the "softmax" of $x_1$, defined as
$$\frac{\exp(x_1)}{\sum_i \exp(x_i)}?$$

The questions here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315476 and [Expectation of a multivariate Gaussian after going through a Softmax](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4256734) seem related, but I cannot find a way to apply the results there.

Comment: I don't expect this to have a closed-form, because it is related to the sum of [log-normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), which does not have closed-form expressions, but you can use [approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Related_distributions).

Comment: Thanks a lot @P.S.Dester

Comment: Is there a way to at least calculate the mean and variance if not the pdf?