# Numerical approximation of expected value of sigmoid function w.r.t Gaussian distribution

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, normal-distribution

I'm reading the book [computer vision:models, learning and inference](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/s.prince/book/book.pdf), in formula (9.19), it proposes to numerically approximate an integration
$\int f(x)g_{\mu,\sigma}(x)dx \approx f(\mu/\sqrt{1+\pi\sigma^2/8}$), where $g_{\mu,\sigma}(x)$ is the density function of a (univariate) Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, and particularly in the book the $f(x)=1/(1+\exp(-x))$ (the sigmoid function).

I just wonder why this is reasonable? There's no hint in the book and I have no idea what's the keyword for the formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piecing together discussions from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207861/expected-value-of-applying-the-sigmoid-function-to-a-normal-distribution) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/how-can-i-calculate-int-infty-infty-phi-left-fracw-ab-right-phiw/61098#61098).

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$. Let $\Phi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ be the CDF and PDF of the standard normal distribution respectively.

> [Lemma 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/381375/43949): $f(x) \approx \Phi(\lambda x)$ where $\lambda=\sqrt{\pi/8}$.

> [Lemma 2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/how-can-i-calculate-int-infty-infty-phi-left-fracw-ab-right-phiw/61098#61098): $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right) \phi(x) \, dx = \Phi\left(\frac{-a}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}\right)$.

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) g_{\mu, \sigma}(x) \, dx
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\sigma u + \mu) \phi(u) \, du
& \text{change of variables}
\\
&\approx \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(\lambda(\sigma u + \mu)) \phi(u) \, du
& \text{Lemma 1}
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi\left(\frac{u + \mu /\sigma}{1/(\sigma \lambda)}\right) \phi(u) \, du
\\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{\mu/\sigma}{\sqrt{(\sigma \lambda)^{-2} + 1}}\right) & \text{Lemma 2}
\\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\lambda^{-2} + \sigma^2}}\right)
\tag{$*$}
\\
&\approx f\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{1 + \sigma^2 \lambda^2}}\right).
& \text{Lemma 1 again}
\end{align}

As a sanity check, ($*$) matches [korkinof's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/381375/43949). Your book takes one more step to approximate $\Phi$ by $f$.

Comment: Very nice answer. One would hope that a textbook would at least contain a hint or reference to such a seemingly audacious estimate.

Comment: Could you explain more about lemma 1? Is the value $\sqrt{\pi/8}$ optimal or it's just an empirical one?

Comment: OK I see, when $\lambda=\sqrt{\pi/8}$ it makes $\Phi(\lambda x)$ tangent to the sigmoid at the origin